# Undefined reference error when using canon EDSDK

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, canon-sdk

I'm developing an application which uses canon EDSDK.

According to documentation, i've moved EDSDK folder into my project folder, included a path to *.h* files and linked the EDSDK library to my project using theese lines of code in my *.pro* file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\QtProjects\EcoGeosPhoto\EDSDK\Header

LIBS += C:\QtProjects\EcoGeosPhoto\EDSDK\Library\EDSDK.lib
```

The paths are correct.

I also included all the *.h* files like so:

```
#include "EDSDK.h"
#include "EDSDKErrors.h"
#include "EDSDKTypes.h"
```

The problem is that when i use simple lines of code, such as:

```
EdsError err = EDS_ERR_OK;
EdsCameraListRef cameraList = nullptr;
err = EdsGetCameraList(&cameraList);
```

compiler complains about "*undefined reference to `__imp_EdsGetCameraList'*".

Am i missing something? Any help is appreciated.

P.s. i'm using MinGW 7.3.0. 64-bit for C++ compiler, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving *.dll* files to the location of the exe file did the trick for me